# how to remove untrack changes but keeping indexed changes

Tags: git, stage, git-index, git-stage

in my git status I see this

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified: file1
modified: file2
modified: file4

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified: file1
modified: file4
```

how can I reset the files to the current staged changes and discarding only the non-staged changes.

Comment: You want to *keep* the staged stuff, but make the work-tree versions of `file1` and `file4` match the staged stuff, so that `git status` shows three modified files ready to commit and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using checkout command, just like that:

```
git checkout file1
git checkout file4
```

Hope this help

Comment: Actually, this will restore file1 and file4 to the staged versions.

Comment: Oh, you're right, `<tree-ish>` defaults to the index, not to `HEAD`.  Sorry about that.  Will delete wrong comment and vote-up answer...